# Isotope- Have an already selected category instead of showing all on loading website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I am writing a code in which I want to filter different categories using isotope in html website using js. I have written the code for filtering and it works fine. When I load the website then all the images are shown. I want to have a particular category selected at the start.

code-

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
    if (portfolioContainer) {
      let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
      });

      let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);

      on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('filter-active');
        });
        this.classList.add('filter-active');

        portfolioIsotope.arrange({
          filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
        });
        portfolioIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
          AOS.refresh()
        });
      }, true);
    }

  });
```

html code-

```
 <li data-filter=".filter-cof">Clip On Frame</li>
      <li data-filter=".filter-ib">Inshop Branding</li>
      <li data-filter=".filter-pf">Photo Frame</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer for this.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
    if (portfolioContainer) {
      let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
//Add the wanted filter here -
filter:'.filter-cof'
      
});

      let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);

      on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('filter-active');
        });
        this.classList.add('filter-active');

        portfolioIsotope.arrange({
          filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
        });
        portfolioIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
          AOS.refresh()
        });
      }, true);
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can just `trigger()` a `click` on the item you want to start with

let's say the url is `index.php?filter=pf`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let w = window.location.search;
  //For demo:
  w = "?filter=filter-pf";
 let s = new URLSearchParams(w)
 if (s.filter) $(`[data-filter='.${s.filter}']`).trigger('click')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I have tried a solution similar to this but then my website doesn't load. It becomes stuck to the loading screen.